# How to use Python's websockets with asyncio in a class and with an existing event loop

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm currently trying to integrate a websocket interface to my program. I'm using the https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html module for this purpose, along with asyncio. I'm currently struggling to implement the websocket functionalites in a dedicated class that sets up the websocket tasks to run in concurrency in the same event loop as the task running in MyDriver class.

main.py

```
from myDriver import MyDriver
from webSocketServer import WebSocketServer

async def main():

   # loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   driver = MyDriver()
   ws = WebSocketServer()
   await driver.drive()
   # The following does not integrate properly with the above. The msgHandler is not ran 
   await websockets.serve(lambda websocket, path: ws.msgHandler(websocket, path), "localhost", 5678)

asyncio.run(main())
```

The lambda is here to get rid of the self argument coming from the class.

webSocketServer.py

```
import asyncio
import websockets

class WebSocketServer:

    def __init__(self):
        print('Init')

    async def msgHandler(self, websocket, path):
        self.sendTask = asyncio.create_task(self.sendHandler(websocket, path))
        self.receiveTask = asyncio.create_task(self.receiveHandler(websocket, path))

        await asyncio.wait([self.sendTask, self.receiveTask], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

    async def sendHandler(self, websocket, path):
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
            message = producer()
            await websocket.send(message)

    async def receiveHandler(self, websocket, path):
        async for message in websocket:
            await self.printMsg()

    async def printMsg(self, msg):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        print(msg)

    def producer():
        return 'Hi !'
```

I based my implementation on the examples provided on the websockets' Getting Started page. They use the `loop.run_until_complete(server)` & `loop.run_forever()` APIs. I also tried to use these by passing the `loop` in argument to the constructor of `WebSocketServer(loop)` and do the `websockets.serve(lambda websocket, path: ws.msgHandler(websocket, path), "localhost", 5678)` there, but then I get the error `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`. I also had a look at `loop.create_task()`, which takes a coroutine as an argument.

Does anyone see a way I could properly integrate a websocket server running in the same event loop as my other task? Thx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> They use the `loop.run_until_complete(server)` & `loop.run_forever()` APIs.

It is good that you converted those to `asyncio.run()`, which is a much more robust way to start up asyncio code. It's just that your conversion is incomplete, it's missing the `run_forever()` part. Something like `run_forever()` is needed because `websockets.serve()` doesn't mean "serve and exit when done", it means "start serving and return a handle to the server". This handle is returned (almost) immediately and if you return from `main` at that point, as your code does, the program will just exit before it has handled a single connection.

What you need to do is add another await at the end of main, where you await for as long as the program needs to run. One way is to `await asyncio.Event().wait()`, which will wait forever and is the await equivalent of `loop.run_forever()`. And since you have the server object at your disposal, you can use its `wait_closed()` method to wait for as long as the server is running (i.e. a coroutine intentionally closes it by calling `server.close()`), which is probably what you want.

In other words, you need to modify the last line of `main()` to:

```
   server = await websockets.serve(lambda websocket, path: ws.msgHandler(websocket, path), "localhost", 5678)
   await server.wait_closed()
```